# Amazon Elasticsearch Service, since upgrade to Amazon Opensearch service is unusably slow

Tags: amazon-elasticsearch, opensearch-dashboards

Amazon OpenSearch Service (successor to Amazon Elasticsearch Service), since the upgrade from Amazon Elasticsearch service, the stock dashboards app has been cripplingly slow. Login, as well as most screen access (e.g. visualizations, dashboards, reports, security, populating drop-down menus, etc) takes multiple minutes, where, prior to the upgrade, these operations would take a few seconds at most.

The collective size of all indices is at around 15-20M

Cloudwatch indicates MasterReachableFromNode has some red bars.
Max JVM Memory Pressure was hovering around 75% but dropped to around 33% after posting a cache clear command (through dev tools), however this did not substantially change the above performance issues.

Elastic search command performance is diminished, although not nearly to the degree of the opensearch UI, open searches used to take 1-2 seconds are now taking 4-5 seconds.

However, tHe AWS Opensearch Service UI is maddeningly slow.

Hoping for some direction (things to check/actions to take/etc) to improve this situation.

Comment: have you found solution to the issue?

Comment: No, but the issue went away a few days later, and has been running pretty well since.